# What are softwares that help as All in one cross browser for CSS?

Tags: css, debugging, browser

I only know IE tester.
What if users are using old versions of safari, chrome, firefox, opera, flock?
Is there any All-in-one browser software for CSS debugging? If not, where can I download old versions of browsers?

Comment: This isn't the type of question for this site, but http://www.oldversion.com/Internet

Answer (score 2):

This tool will be of use to you: http://www.browserstack.com

Quote:

> We provide real IE6, IE7, IE8, IE9 and all versions of Firefox,
>   Safari, Chrome and Opera for testing. With a complete browser stack at
>   your fingertips, you’ll deliver effective web pages to more than 99.5%
>   of your users.

It's a paid for tool, but if you are a developer making money or for a big company it's worth it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try Adobe's Browser Lab for free. You just need free a account for use if you dont have.

Here the link: https://browserlab.adobe.com

Answer (score 1):

Multi-Browser Viewer >> http://www.multibrowserviewer.com

Microsoft SuperPreview >> http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/SuperPreview_Overview.aspx

I use them :)

Answer (score 1):

What about user-agent for chrome or what ever your favorit browser is?

its a free solution to your problem, Play around with them, it even show view-ports for tablets, phones and so on!

Just get the item string and then enter it as a new device to your user agent tester, i pref chrome which extension you find **[HERE](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg?hl=da)** their are several different once but i like this one

Comment: It won't render differently though, as in the CSS that the person wants?

Comment: It will only show the site rules if set for IE or mobile etc, however the rendering engine will still be the main browser not the faked user agent.

Comment: thats true but you can mostly css using different browseres

Comment: You can, however there are some major quirks between different browsers which require actual rendering engines to see what is happening.